# How to "show databases" which belong to a specific user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, show, privileges

"show databases" shows all databases where you (logged in user) have some privileges.

Is there a way to show all databases where user "xxx" has some privileges?

Edit:
I have an user "mickey":

```
mysql> show grants for mickey;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mickey@%                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mickey'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*B9E506CBC9D7D8352A3C02DBC94677A5DEF491B8' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mickey\_%`.* TO 'mickey'@'%'                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

User mickey is allowed to create/drop databases and tables with name "mickey_%". Filtering out these databases is easy but only because his databases have prefix "mickey_".

there is one databases called "mickey_example2" where mickey has all privileges. I am not able to find this database in information_schema or mysql db.

And this ist the only information about 'mickey' in information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%mickey%';
+--------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE      | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE | IS_GRANTABLE |
+--------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| 'mickey'@'%' | def           | USAGE          | NO           |
+--------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

[MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html) says:

> MySQL implements databases as directories in the data directory, so
>   this statement simply lists directories in that location. However, the
>   output may include names of directories that do not correspond to
>   actual databases.

which means to me that there does not have to be any information (about existing databases) avaiable in information_schema, especially if the database is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching and reading I found out that there is no nice and clean way to find "show databases" for other users.

I have changed my db design by doing following:
- every database name begins with $username_
- $username cannot contain underline "_"

and I have a user without any grants except "SHOW DATABASES" and I found user's databases using WHERE LIKE with SHOW DATABASES command:

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` LIKE ?
```

and ? is replaced with:

```
'$username\_%'
```

Comment: Im on a shared server. "SHOW DATABASES" was taking 20 seconds to show me my 3 databases. using your solution it's instantaneous now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the privileges for a given user querying the table USER_PRIVILEGES from "information_schema".

For instance, to test "CREATE" privileges for a user named "root" you could query:

> SELECT * FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES WHERE GRANTEE LIKE
>   "'root'%" AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE="CREATE";

Comment: that does not work. see my edit. there is nothing about "mickey" in user_privileges.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Host, Db, User from mysql.db;
```

This will show you your host, database name and corresponding user all in one